# Best book about modernism typography

Tags: typography, resource-recommendations, education, book

"Grid systems in graphic design" by *Josef Müller Brockmann* is THE book about the modular grid system and deals with layout. The "Vignelli Canon" by Massimo Vignelli partly deals with modernistic typography but it's very basic. "The New Typography" exists of course.

– Is there a book about typography seen through (swiss), mid century modernistic eyes that goes more deep into hierarchy, lists, tables, etc? An equivalent to "Elements of Typographic Style" by *Robert Bringhurst*.

Answer (score 1):

This is a small, short book that's very good at summarizing a lot of ideas on typesetting — "Detail In Typography" by Jost Hochuli.

[image]